# tf.layers.batch_normalization not working within for loop of dense layers

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to play around with batch_normalization in GCMLE and I'm getting the error:

```
ValueError: Variable dense/batch_norm/batch_normalization/gamma already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True or reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope?
```

My code is as follows:

```
with tf.variable_scope('hidden_layer'):    
  for layer_size in hidden_units:
      hidden_layer = tf.layers.dense(hidden_layer,layer_size, activation=tf.nn.relu)
      hidden_layer = tf.layers.batch_normalization(hidden_layer, axis = -1, training = mode == Modes.TRAIN)
```

I have also then added the update_ops as instructed:

```
update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
  train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=params.learning_rate, epsilon = params.epsilon)
  gradients, variables = zip(*train_op.compute_gradients(loss))
  optimize = train_op.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, variables), global_step=global_step)
```

My first guess for the cause of the error is that it is trying to reuse the variables created throughout the for loop `hidden_layer/dense/batch_norm/batch_normalization/gamma` but the documentation for reuse suggests this is `Boolean, whether to reuse the weights of a previous layer by the same name.` -- if this issue were being created by the for loop, wouldn't the second time through the loop have the name `hidden_layer/dense_1/...`? The code works fine if I only add one hidden layer, so I'm not sure how to adjust.

Comment: Have you tried `with tf.variable_scope('hidden_layer', reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):`?

Comment: No No No Richard. The solution is to properly **name** all layers differently using `(..., name='bn_%i'% I)`. You cannot use auto_reuse when the number of hidden units is different. Further it makes no sense to reuse. Further the loop is incorrect, the layer dense should use the input `hidden_layer` as well. Otherwise you do not stack them.

Comment: @Patwie. I had made a mistake when I typed it in - yes `hidden_layer` would also be stacked. How come the layers in batch_normalization do not get automatically named `_%`` like the dense layers do? Could you further explain `auto_reuse` -- you suggest that you cannot use it when the number of hidden units is different, but if it were the same that would be fine? Could you clarify that logic further?

Comment: Not being able to use auto_reuse for hidden layers with different numbers of units intuitively makes sense. How/why would you reuse variables which are different? Also, regarding the dense layers being automatically named: can you elaborate a bit on that?